# Default select option by table column (with Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm about to perform a huge data input in a table with three `select` options divided by three columns.

I would like to have the *First* `select` with the **first option** selected by default; the *Second* `select` with the **second option** selected by default; and the *Third* `select` with the **third option** selected by default.

Something like:

```
     Select 1   | Select 2   | Select 3    
    ------------+------------+-------------
     *Option A* | Option A   | Option A    
     Option B   | *Option B* | Option B    
     Option C   | Option C   | *Option C*
```

Those options selected by default in each select.

The problem is that each `select` has its own ID, there are many pages and more than 500 different selects... Each `select` is inside a column `<td>` that I think I can add an unique ID to each column (no matter how many pages, ending with three columns with three unique IDs)

I really have no idea how to achieve this; I was wondering if anyone could come up with a possible solution or orientation so I can take a look with more detail.

Thank you for your time,
Regards

Comment: The name of each `select` is also unique (it's the same as the ID)...

Comment: You can target the selectedIndex javscript property to pre-select the index incrementally. $('select').each(function(){ $(this)[0].selectedIndex = i });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the `selectedIndex` javascript property and have the option selected via a variable that you can increment. This way, you don't have to assign individual id's to each select.

```
var i = 0;
    $('select').each(function()
    {
       $(this)[0].selectedIndex = i;
       i++;
    });
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/4m18yzx6/

To select them inside the td,

```
$('table tr td').each(function()
{
   var i = 0;
   $(this).find('select').each(function()
   {
     $(this)[0].selectedIndex = i;
     i++;
   }) 
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/4m18yzx6/1/

Comment: Hello. It works perfect and is exactly what I'm looking for! . I appreciate your time; however I was wondering how could I make it run here, the actual html table: https://jsfiddle.net/25c0fvcy/1/ The column called "Grade" should be left empty as it is by default; and before those `select` fields, there are a few others, so I think I have to contain the table inside a `div`). **If you can't/won't do it I totally understand!**

Comment: You just need to exclude the first 2 td's in each tr. Fixed here : https://jsfiddle.net/25c0fvcy/2/

Comment: Actually, you just need to skip the 1st select, and set the property on the later ones. This is the correct version : https://jsfiddle.net/25c0fvcy/3/

Comment: Sure. Glad to help :)